# i can't add android sdk to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I can't add android sdk to eclipse.I download android sdk and i can't see anything in red circle area on picture which is below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the ADT from the Site, just give .zip file name to Work With: Option.

And ya it is done.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you should click the "Add" button, assign a name and put the url to the "Location" field.

Answer (score 2):

just try http instead of https...i was facing the same problem

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Extract ADT 16

**now go to ADT 16 -> puguins- >**

copy all jar files from here

go to

**eclipse -> plugins -> PASTE all jar files here**

restart eclipse...